# Rspec: Transactional fixtures do not work after upgrading to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have the following line set in spec_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

This means that every test should cleanup after itself. Any db update made by one test should not be around for the next test.

I have two tests in one of my spec files.

```
it 'should update the DB' do
  Setting.put('abcd', 'efgh')
end

it 'should not find the DB update' do
  Setting.get('abcd').should be_nil
end
```

The above two test used to work with Rails 3.2.14

However after upgrading to Rails 4, the second test fails with the following error,

```
------
expected: nil
got: "efgh"
-----
```

I have about a 100 tests failing in the suite because of this issue.

The only related documentation I can find for Rails 4 upgrade was something quite vague:
"Rails 4.0 has deprecated ActiveRecord::Fixtures in favor of ActiveRecord::FixtureSet."

I am not sure if/how this is relevant. I would ideally like to have a global setting (config.use_transactional_fixtures = true), and not have to change the logic of the tests (or add extra before(:each)/after(:each) modules just to get existing tests to pass. Please help!

Comment: It looks like a problem with `rspec-rails`. Try upgrading to `rspec-rails 2.13.1`. Have a look at this issue too -> https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10376

Comment: @Vimsha, I tried both 2.13.1 and 2.14.1 but the issue seems to persist. :(

Comment: related? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10376

Comment: `puts RSpec.configuration.use_transactional_fixtures` - check if it's really true.

Comment: Are you doing feature testing as well? If you're turning it off for something else it might be leaking over. If you could post your `spec_helper` and `setting.rb` file, that would be helpful.

Comment: Did anyone figure out a solution to this? I have the same problem, I can spam refresh on a table (users) for my database and watch the thing going up and down in records, it eventually finishes all tests and the result is a table with different records to what the fixtures specify... ??? I have printed `RSpec.configuration.use_transactional_fixtures` and its true

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue (with rspec-rails 3.1) on rails 4.1. Didn't have auto-run running, although I did have spring, which may be the culprit. 
However, I decided to try an alternative, which worked nicely: database cleaner, which does a similar job:
https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

So add to Gemfile:

```
group :test do
...
  gem 'database_cleaner'
...
end
```

Then change to rails helper:

```
  #Database cleaning
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false #IMPORTANT, make sure that rails doesn't try and clean it
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction #usually use transaction as the strategy - this is what transaction_fixtures does
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) # I like to ensure my database is in clean state to start with so I truncate at the start of the suite - this is optional.
  end 

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

For me removing

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

from spec_helper made things worked fine.

I had zeus server running. Symptoms were if i run test with zeus server transaction would get saved into the Test DB.

When zeus server was not running the rspec would work fine.

To make it work with Zeus server i had to autorun.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, that it's same problem. But for me the solution was - to create data only in "it" do/end block. And if you create data in context it doesn't work.

that's works:

```
    context "with array of both exista and non exist words" do

      clean_words = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]

      language = "eng"
      it "return array of word, that exist in Word class" do
        word = FactoryGirl.create(:word)
        word2 = FactoryGirl.create(:word, name: "bar")
        exist_words = [word, word2]
        expect(Word.generate_list_of_exist_words(clean_words, language).sort).to eq exist_words.sort

      end
    end
```

that's not works:

```
    context "with array of both exista and non exist words" do

      clean_words = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]
      word = FactoryGirl.create(:word)
      word2 = FactoryGirl.create(:word, name: "bar")
      exist_words = [word, word2]
      language = "eng"
      it "return array of word, that exist in Word class" do

        expect(Word.generate_list_of_exist_words(clean_words, language).sort).to eq exist_words.sort

      end
    end
```

Comment: Yes, I was creating data outside the `it` block so it was persisting. I suggest wrapping such data in a `before do` block if applicable

Answer (score 0):

As one comment suggested, this is likely an issue with rspec-rails (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10376). Try upgrading to `rspec-rails 2.13.1` or higher:

`bundle update --source rspec-rails`